# Using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider with SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, sqlmembershipprovider, activedirectorymembership

I want to create a web-app (a website) used in house by staff only.

I want to use active directory membersip provider to authenticate users.
The thing that is confusing me is how do I manage profiles and roles, and also link users with a FK to other tables.

So far Im thinking of doing something like this but not sure if it is even possible?

- use Windows authentication (set in web.config)
- use activedirectorymembership provider + sqlmembership provider?
- Register users the first time they hit the site (get their email, name, etc from AD and create user in code and add to sql db)
- Everytime they re-hit the site, check the db if the user exists, if they do, log them in, if not create a new user in sqlmembership.
- for all other tables use userid from Aspnet_User as an FK in other tables

Will this even work? or is there a better obvious way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588265/understanding-wcf-windows-authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the ActiveDirectory Membership provider, you're authenticating your users against your Active Directory - there's no separate membership database involved (the user accounts are in Active Directory).

The role provider is using the Active Directory/Windows security groups and a user's membership in those groups - again: no separate role database / table involved.

If you want to use the Active Directory provider, then each new user coming to your site would need to be added to your Active Directory as a regular user account.

You cannot use both membership providers at the same time - **either** you're going against your AD and use the user accounts and groups defined there - **(exclusive) OR** you're rolling your own, and store user accounts and roles and user's membership in roles in a separate SQL Server database.

Comment: I think this is more what I am after http://goo.gl/qrhTP. what do you reckon? also how about uniquely representing the user (with pk/fk) in the db - how should that be managed?

Comment: @raklos: yes, that blog post shows how to use the SqlRoleProvider - there's no mention of the ActiveDirectoryProvider anywhere .... you're using Windows Authentication for detecting the user names - but you'll have to create a "Roles" table in SQL Server, and fill it there. The AD provider isn't involved here in any way, really...

Answer (score 0):

could you create a custom role and profile provider?

than you can use the windows username as fk, to reference the user to their roles and profiles.